# Negate integer Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an integer variable which can contain either a `0` or a `1`. It is not a `boolean`, rather a representation of an `enum` in C#.

What is the shortest way of rewriting this ternary function such that when `sourceNumber` is 1, `targetNumber` is set to 0, when `sourceNumber` is 0, `targetNumber` is set to 1?

```
var sourceNumber = 1;
var targetNumber = sourceNumber == 1 ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: You may use bitwise NOT: `targetNumber = ~sourceNumber`

Comment: @hindmost Are you really sure ?

Comment: @hindmost `~0 == -1` and `~1 == -2`

Comment: `~` is classically used in JS to swap `0` and `-1` (most frequent use : `if (~a.indexOf(b)){...`)

Comment: @dystroy, @RGraham I was wrong. Correct answer: `targetNumber = Number(!sourceNumber)`

Comment: @hindmost This is a completely different answer (doing first a conversion to boolean and then a conversion to number). This is very very slow, even when simplified in `+(!sourceNumber)`. See jsperf in my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short and [efficient](http://jsperf.com/swap-0-and-1) :

```
var targetNumber = 1 - sourceNumber;
```

Comment: Seems so simple once I see it written down! Thanks.